# Html Code not able to preview the image

Tags: html, blat

I am trying to open an image in html webpage and send that page through Emailer.
so that it appears as a pic in the email.

but not able to do it.

Html code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta content="HTML Tidy for Windows>
     <title>
       Test
    </title>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;">
   </head>  <body background="cid:C:/pic.jpeg">
```

When I open the webpage it appears blank.

Could somebody guide me the error.

regards,..chio

Answer (score 1):

You have a few typos in that document. Make sure that you are defining the document as HTML in blat as well. Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
 <html>
   <head>
     <meta name="description" content="HTML Tidy for Windows">
     <title>
       Test
    </title>
     <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
   </head>  
<body background="cid:C:/pic.jpeg">
</body>
</html>
```

You can also try setting the background in CSS:

```
<body style="background-image:url(cid:C:/pic.jpeg);background-size:cover">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing Jpeg and type .jpg instead
and if still occurs have a look at this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name="description" content="HTML Tidy for Windows">
     <title>
         Test
     </title>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
    </head>  
<body background="C:/pic.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

I removed `cid:` as well from your code